# undefined reference to function in arhive

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I am receiving the old "undefined reference to " with the following code

```
BYTE byteT = '0';
DSTATUS diskStatus = disk_initialize(byteT);
```

The exact error is:

```
fileSystemController.cpp:13: undefined reference to `disk_initialize(unsigned char)'
```

This function is defined in an archive file called libxilffs.a. This archive file is composed of two object files ff.o and diskio.o.

I am able to call all functions that are inside the ff.o object file, but i not any of the function defined in the diskio.o object file

I ran nm on the archived and this is the output

```
ff.o:
00000000 b .LANCHOR0
00000000 r .LANCHOR1
00000000 r .LC0
         U __aeabi_uidiv
000000d8 t check_fs
00000190 t chk_mounted
00000f50 T clust2sect
0000087c t create_chain
000009ec t dir_next
00000bd8 t dir_sdi.constprop.6
         U disk_initialize
         U disk_ioctl
         U disk_read
         U disk_status
         U disk_write
00000000 r excvt.5690
00001a58 T f_close
00001a70 T f_lseek
00000fb4 T f_mount
00000ff0 T f_open
00001cc8 T f_opendir
0000134c T f_read
00001d74 T f_readdir
00001874 T f_sync
00001594 T f_write
00000000 b FatFs
00000cd0 t follow_path
00000004 b Fsid
00000f74 T get_fat
00000610 t get_fat.part.4
         U get_fattime
00000000 t move_window
00000f94 T put_fat
00000728 t put_fat.part.5
000005d0 t validate

diskio.o:
00000000 b .LANCHOR0
00000048 T disk_initialize
00000208 T disk_ioctl
0000019c T disk_read
00000000 T disk_status
00000264 T disk_write
00000200 C ExtCsd
00000258 T get_fattime
00000020 b SdInstance
00000000 b Stat
         U Xil_In32
         U XSdPs_CfgInitialize
         U XSdPs_Change_BusSpeed
         U XSdPs_Change_BusWidth
         U XSdPs_Change_ClkFreq
         U XSdPs_Get_BusSpeed
         U XSdPs_Get_BusWidth
         U XSdPs_LookupConfig
         U XSdPs_Pullup
         U XSdPs_ReadPolled
         U XSdPs_SdCardInitialize
         U XSdPs_Select_Card
         U XSdPs_SetBlkSize
         U XSdPs_WritePolled
```

As you can see the disk_initialize function is defined in the archive file... but i cant use it, i get fileSystemController.cpp:13: undefined reference to `disk_initialize(unsigned char)'.

So my question is this, is there some way that parts of the archive file are unavailable to me when other parts are available?

here is my command line compile contents:

```
arm-xilinx-eabi-g++ -Wl,-T -Wl,../src/lscript.ld -L../../standalone_bsp_0/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib -o "ABC.elf" obfile1.o ........ -Wl,--start-group,-lgcc,-lc,-lstdc++,-lxilffs,-lxil,--end-group
```

Where (bfile1.o ........) is a whole bunch of object files.

Comment: You say `c++` in the tags. Might it be that you are looking for the wrong overloaded function? You sure it takes single `unsigned char`?

Comment: here is the definition of the function "DSTATUS disk_initialize (BYTE);" where BYTE is "typedef unsigned char   BYTE;"

Comment: Tried unpacking the archive and linking directly with `diskio.o`?

Comment: Someone forgot to add `extern "C"` to that function declaration.

Comment: ahh. Yes that is one difference between the two object files in the archive. The one i can call functions from does have the "extern "C" " defined where the one that is giving me problems doesn't have this.... i gues this is the source of the problem

Comment: I went through and added the extern "C"  to the offending header file in it looks like the issue is still there?

Comment: Also if the problem had to do with the extern "C" not being there wouldn't the names be mangled for the functions defined in the header files without the extern "C"?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see the disk_initialize function is defined in the archive file

I can not see it. `nm` shows status `disk_initialize U` which means "symbol is undefined" [refer to nm docs please](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)

The whole case is: your `libxilffs.a` references this function (may be even uses it somewhere inside) but neither exports, nor even defines it.

In the first place you need to figure out where this function really should come from.

P.S. And switching telepathy mode on. I may advise you to look at FatFs library, which have very similar function inside.

Comment: ahh. I didn't notice the U in the ff.o section for the disk_initialize function. When i said it was defined i mean later in the file "00000048 T disk_initialize", but that is under the diskio.o section...

Answer (score 0):

So n.m had the write answer i added the

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

To the appropiate header file and it found the function.

Thanks for the help